# Display the currently saved file even when the admin does not validate the model

Tags: django, django-admin, django-validation

To illustrate my problem, consider this (useless) model:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField('File')
    def clean(self):
        super(MyModel, self).clean()
        raise ValidationError('Err')
```

When a new file is selected in the admin site before saving, clicking on the Save button returns a page that displays the error 'Err' (as expected), but the file field does not show the *currently saved file* of the model. (I am not talking about the new file that the user tries to upload.)

What I see is something like this:

[image: Wrong field]

while I expected:

[image: Right field]

The problem does not occur when no new file to upload is selected. And when I see the problem, refreshing the page displays the file path again, so it is still saved as expected.

How can make sure the currently saved file will always be displayed, even when I raise a validation error?

(Django 1.9.8)

Comment: I commented on the exact same question minutes ago, maybe taking a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504953/rendering-modelform-with-imagefield-validation-errors?noredirect=1#comment64410886_38504953